# Is <context: annotation-config> necessary for annotation @Resource , @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy?

Tags: spring

I am new in spring and i want to know that if i write @Resource or @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy annotation on any method of any class then it is necessary to add "context: annotation-config" tag in xml file to register the method.

My confusion is that @Resource or @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy are JSR-250 annotation which are not specific to spring-framework then why "context: annotation-config" tag is added in config file(spring.xml).

I know that it is applicable for @Required and for @Autowired annotation.

Can anyone explain please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is this that, no matter what the annotation is, actually it doesn't do anything, it just is kind of mark that tell the other thing that what it means. And when you add `context: annotation-config` in your xml file, when you start up the tomcat or other which will load the environment of Spring, then when it found `context: annotation-config`, it will register some beans that Spring has implemented which will scan your class to find annotation @Resource or @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy, and do the thing that it will actually do, such as instantiate Bean, bind the value and so on.